# how to set the culture to french by button click

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have added resources-fr-FR in the resource directory

and in the button click I have added the below code

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

but this does not work

Comment: Please can you give more details than "this does not work". What happens (or doesn't happen)? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: If you mean that an already localized window/page doesn't seems to react to that instruction, it's because (and this could be your case) it has no effect on already opened window/page. Have to re-open.

Comment: @ chris : I meant the culture doesn ot change it remain as english, if I click on the button that updates the culture  .

Comment: @NestorArturo : yes ! I have done localisation uses resources files . I wish to change the culture by button click without reopening the file.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure what to do besides telling the user that this change will be applied the next time they open the window/page. Sorry, not really sure how to implement this "immediate" localization" you need. As far as I know if you use the classic "UID" property in controls you have to re-open.